# Aspect Ratio for div and its elements

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm building an HTML5 game without canvas and want to keep a 16:9 ratio for my div. That is easily done by javascript and it works perfectly well. But the elements inside the div itself, they sometime become too big (if the screen is big). I'm aware of max/min-height/width, but is there any other way to make it as if the game is scaled?

here is the code for js and css:

```
function fix() {
    var gameWidth = $(window).width();
    var gameHeight = $(window).height();
    var fitX = gameWidth / 800;
    var fitY = gameHeight / 480;


    var screenRatio = gameWidth / gameHeight;
    var optimalRatio = Math.min(fitX, fitY);


    // checking ratio
    if( screenRatio >= 1.77 && screenRatio <= 1.79)
    {
        $('#game').width ($(window).Width + 'px');
        $('#game').height ($(window).Height + 'px');
    } 
    else 
    {
        $('#game').width (800 * optimalRatio + 'px');
        $('#game').height (480 * optimalRatio + 'px');
    }

    $('#game').center();
}
```

the function is doing its job perfectly well. 
but the CSS here is what I'm having issues with.

```
#game {
    width: 800px;
    height: 480px;
    background: url(bg.png);
    position: relative;
}

.landing {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    max-width: 190px;
    height: 60%;
    max-height: 290px;
    bottom: 10%;
    background: #ff6600;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I want it so that the landing scales while keeping the 190/290 ratio..
thanks.

Comment: A simple way use precents for that. I mean use a width for main div and for other elements inside it use precents.

Comment: I'm doing that atm.. but the issue is when the screen is too big, the element loses its ratio. =.=
screenshots to clarify what I mean: 
small screen: [link]http://prntscr.com/1w6jgd
large screen: [link]http://prntscr.com/1w6jh5

Comment: I can't understand what you mean but there are two things you may mean. one you want to have things in a fixed ratio so if the screen gets bigger then you want the elements to stay small (ie one element always be 40px*60px) and second you want an element to always be 10% percent of screen. which of them you meant?

Comment: what I mean is that I want the scaled element's size not to get too out of control for unexpected results..
I'm using max-height/width now but it doesn't feel right...

Comment: OK you can do it in two ways one use three , four or etc sizes + responsive view and the second way is two use the precents and then you can have your window size at any size you want but I suggest you first type.

Comment: Do you have in mind that percentage height will be calculated relative to the parents *width* and not the *height*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Not percents will be the way but 'em' units.

Set the font-size of the outer div to 10px then 1.0em equals 10 Pixels. If you use 'em' for every element inside you just change font-size of outer div and everything else get's scaled.

CAVE: Nested 'em' font-sizes will multiply so only use these on the 'leaf' elements, that have no children. At least no children which use 'em' units themselves

What will be the advantage? You don't have to fiddle around with the scale of the outer element with jQuery.

If you want to depend on the available space you should act on window resizes with jquery and only change the outer wrap font-size in that case and all will be well

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/a8yc7/

#### HTML

```
<button class="five">50%</button>
<button class="ten">100%</button>
<button class="fifteen">150%</button>
<button class="twenty">200%</button>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="elem elem1"></div>
        <div class="elem elem2"></div>
        <div class="elem elem3"></div>
        <div class="elem elem4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.wrap {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.container {
    width: 30em;
    height: 20em;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.elem {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
}

.elem1 {
    background: silver;
    top: 8em;
    left: -5em;
}
.elem2 {
    background: green;
    top: -2em;
    left: 12em;
}
.elem3 {
    background: gray;
    top: -3em;
    left: 13em;
}
.elem4 {
    background: red;
    top: 5em;
    left: 2em;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$('.five').on('click', function() {
    $('.wrap').css({
        fontSize: '5px'
    })
})
$('.ten').on('click', function() {
    $('.wrap').css({
        fontSize: '10px'
    })
})
$('.fifteen').on('click', function() {
    $('.wrap').css({
        fontSize: '15px'
    })
})
$('.twenty').on('click', function() {
    $('.wrap').css({
        fontSize: '20px'
    })
})
```

Comment: For some reason, I kept thinking that em should not be used for elements. Anyway, used this idea to make the font-size equals to game's width / 100. so 8 if 800 and so on. Thanks. :-)